# Why doesn't the python str.strip() method remove the leading characters in this code?

Tags: python, string, strip

I was using `str.strip('0')` in the below. This is not working for the leading zeros in the below code.

```
str1 = " 0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
str1mod = str1.strip('0')
print str1mod
print len(str1mod)
str2 = "0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
str2mod = str2.strip('0')
print str2mod
print len(str2mod)
```

The output comes like

```
 0000000this is string example....wow!!!
40
this is string example....wow!!!
32
```

*Why is the leading spaces not removed in **str1**?*

Expectation was to get a output like

```
 this is string example....wow!!!
40
this is string example....wow!!!
32
```

Comment: "Why is the leading spaces not removed"... because you didn't tell Python to do that? You told it to remove 0s, not spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `str.strip([chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string **with the leading and trailing characters removed**. The `chars` argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or `None`, the `chars` argument defaults to removing whitespace.

Emphasis mine.

`strip` only removes **leading or trailing** characters. Since the sequence of `0`s is not leading -- it's preceded by a space -- it's not stripped.

If you want to remove characters from anywhere in the string, use `str.remove`.

If you have more complicated needs, use `re.sub` e.g. to remove leading and trailing 0s even if they're preceded by space you can use something along the lines of

```
re.sub(r'^(\s*)(0*)([^0]*)(0*)$', r'\1\3')
```

Comment: Example for the code to strip `0` and space: `str1mod = str1.strip(' 0')`.

Comment: Yes, however looking a the original snippets it looks like the author wants to strip the 0s without touching the rest.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that. In that case your regex is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, the zeroes aren't actually "leading", they are preceded by a space, so what you have to do is to strip the string twice:

```
str1 = " 0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
str1mod = str1.strip().strip('0')
print str1mod
print len(str1mod)
str2 = "0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
str2mod = str2.strip('0')
print str2mod
print len(str2mod)
```

Output in Python 2 shell:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str1 = " 0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
>>> str1mod = str1.strip().strip('0')
>>> print str1mod
this is string example....wow!!!
>>> print len(str1mod)
32
>>> str2 = "0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
>>> str2mod = str2.strip('0')
>>> print str2mod
this is string example....wow!!!
>>> print len(str2mod)
32
>>> 
>>>
```